# Pass data from different controllers to one view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I am developping ASP.NET MVC5 SPA. I have file called `HomeController.cs` and it's view called `_Home.cshtml`.

I'd like to implement current logic: when user enter on `_Home` view application connects to repository and get some data, then fill that data on view into `<li></li>` element.

Here my full `HomeController.cs` class

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{


    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //I am not sure if this code should be in Index method

        //Assume, that data is taken from repository, but it's no matter
        var contactsListModels = new List<ContactListModel>()
        {
            new ContactListModel() {FirstName = "Fred", LastName = "Perry"},
            new ContactListModel() {FirstName = "Jon", LastName = "Skeet"}
        };

        //In some way need to pass it into _Home.cshtml

        return View();
    }

}
```

And part of `_Home.css`

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="col-contacts">
        <div class="col-contacts-textbox-and-contacts">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />

            <!-- Manually added data, but it has to be automatically passed from repository-->
            <ul>
                <li>Jon Skeet</li>
                <li>Fred Perry</li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the title is about, but it looks like you need to create a _view model_ and pass it to your view, e.g. `return View(myViewModel);`.

Comment: In the action method `return View(contactsListModels);` and in the view, add `@model List<ContactListModel>` then create you html in a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am already found excellent solution for my question on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/687061/Multiple-Models-in-a-View-in-ASP-NET-MVC-MVC). It could be accomlished in multiple ways.